# getElementById using a compiled Id with variable part doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

Although `cf_form_<?php echo $module->id;?>` resolves to a valid Id *"cf_form_593"* the `getElementById()` doesn't work. How can I change this?

```
<script>
        function openForm() {
            document.getElementById("cf_form_<?php echo $module->id;?>").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closeForm() {
            document.getElementById("cf_form_593").style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
```

HTML output:

```
<div>
    <div id="cf_wrapp_all_593" class="cf_wrapp_all cf_wrapp_all mobiel">
    <div id="cf_ajax_loader_593"></div>

    <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Filter</button>

    <script>
        function openForm() {
            document.getElementById("cf_form_593").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closeForm() {
            document.getElementById("cf_form_593").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

    <div class="form-popup" id="cf_form_593">

        <form method="get" action="/filter-resuls/" class="form-container" id="cf_form_593">
<p>....</p>
<button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you get on the console? can you also add the html here?

Comment: [The code you have shown should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/3r90vzkm/) (assuming `cf_form_<?php echo $module->id;?>` indeed evaluates to `cf_form_593`). Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code after your edit [seems to work fine as well](https://jsfiddle.net/7rtvj4g0/). The only issue is that you have two `id` attributes with the same identifier. That is not allowed. `id` are required to be unique within the same document.

Comment: Solved it, by using different unique Id attributes.